# GTK+ 3.0 with Glade 3.10: signal handler not found, menu not showing

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

I've written a very simple program with Glade 3.16.1 and GTK+ 3.0 (version 3.10.8) but almost nothing works.

Signal handler gtk_main_quit is not found and the menu is not displayed.

I build the program with

```
gcc gtktest.c -o gtktest -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0)
```

Source code (gtktest.c):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

void kleine_callback (GtkWidget *w, gpointer d)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL,
    GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, "Hallo, Welt!");
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
}

void quit (GtkWidget * w, gpointer d)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GError *error = NULL;
    GtkWidget *window;
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    if (!gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "kaixN.glade", &error)) {        
        g_warning ("%s", error->message);
        g_free (error);
        return 1;
    }
    gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object (builder,  "main_window"));
    gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="width_request">600</property>
    <property name="height_request">400</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="main_vbox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuBar" id="main_menu">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menuitem1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Datei</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu1">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="menu_item_add">
                        <property name="label">gtk-add</property>
                        <property name="related_action"/>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="menu_help">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">_Hilfe</property>
                <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                <child type="submenu">
                  <object class="GtkMenu" id="menu3">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="menu_item_quit">
                        <property name="label">gtk-quit</property>
                        <property name="use_action_appearance">True</property>
                        <property name="related_action"/>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="use_underline">True</property>
                        <property name="use_stock">True</property>
                        <signal name="select" handler="quit" swapped="no"/>
                      </object>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkStatusbar" id="status_bar">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="margin_left">10</property>
            <property name="margin_right">10</property>
            <property name="margin_top">6</property>
            <property name="margin_bottom">6</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="spacing">2</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="pack_type">end</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Everything is so simple, I can't see what I'm doing wrong...
Thx
Kai

Comment: A little less than 24 hrs after my post still no reply... I'm thinking about uninstalling gtk+ 3.0 and continue with gtk+ 2.0 because I can't find any resources with both glade 3 and gtk+ 3... Most tutorials cover glade 3 with gtk+ 2.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was:

1: Signals weren't connected correctly to events.
2: The menu is there but I looked simply at the wrong place. I'm using Ubuntu with Unity so the menu is showing up at the top of the monitor and not at the top of the application window. This post brought my attention to the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/460819/ubuntu-gtk-3-10-8-not-able-to-visualize-a-menubar-made-by-glade